# Why this JSON documents seems to be invalid?

Tags: javascript, json

I am not so into JSON document and I have a problem. I am trying to validate this simple JSON document with: https://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "forecast": [
        "day": [],
        "day": []
    ]
}
```

**forecast** is an array of meteo forecasts, **day** is an array that will contain some object related to morning, afternoon, night forecasts for a specific day. I will enrich it in a second time.

The problem is that when I try to validate this document I obtain the following error message by the previous validator tool:

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...forecast": [     "day": [],      "day": []   ]
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```

Why? What is the problem? How can I create a correct structure like this?

Comment: An array holds primitives not key:value pairs.

Answer (score 4):

An array `[]` contains a **list** of values.

A set of `"property": value` pairs needs to be expressed as an object `{}`.

What's more, while duplicate property names are (technically) allowed in an object, only the last value will be accepted.

Perhaps you are trying to create an array of objects?

```
{
    "forecast": [
        { "day": [] },
        { "day": [] }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"forecast": [
    "day": [],
    "day": []
]
```

the `forecast` key contains an object, not an array, so needs to be:

```
"forecast": {
    "day1": [],
    "day2": []
}
```

or

```
"forecast": [
    { "day": [] },
    { "day": [] }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "day" is in an array, but you're using it like an object ("property: value" notation). 
Either change the square braces to curly braces or use the appropriate array structure. Makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

forecase should actually be an object, not an array.

```
{
"forecast": {
    "day": [],
    "day": []
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In JSON files array stands new objects or the value selfe like:

```
{
    "forecast": [{
            "day": []
        },
        {
            "day": []
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "forecast": [
        ["morning", " afternoon", " night"],
        ["morning", "afternoon", " night"]
    ]
}
```